# Question about continuity of piecewise function of two variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Let $$
f(x,y)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \left(x\sin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),\frac{\cos (y) -1}{y}\right) & x \neq 0 \wedge y \neq 0 \\
      (0,0) & x = 0 \vee y = 0 \\
\end{array} 
\right. 
$$

Is f continuous?

My approach: For $x \neq 0 \wedge y \neq 0$, f is continuous because the composition of continuous functions is continuous. For $x = 0$ and $y = 0$ I look at the sequence $(1/n,1/n)$ and look at the value of f as n goes to infinity. The result is also $(0,0)$.

Now my question is, whether it's sufficient to look at one sequence? I know that the sequence criterion should be valid for any sequences, so if I only look at $(1/n,1/n)$, that actually wouldn't prove the continuity correct?

Also another question is whether I also would have to look at the points where x approaches 0, but y does not and the points where y approaches 0, but x does not?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "correct".  Regarding the second question, you don't *have* too, but if it is case that the function isn't continuous, then it might suffice. As it turns out, the function is continuous because each of the components converges to $0$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how I could prove that the function is continuous at (0,0)?

Comment: You probably already know that it's enough to prove that each coordinate is continuous and the limit is $0$. Is this true? Then do that.  Can you prove that $\lim \limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\left(\dfrac{\cos(y)-1}{y}\right)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not sufficient to look at a sequence. Can you find a counterexample?

However, you have $$\vert x\sin(\frac{y}{x}) \vert \le \vert x \vert$$ for $x \neq 0$ so $f$ first component is continuous. And the second is also continuous as $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\cos y - 1}{y}=\cos^\prime (0)$$

Finally a $f$ is continuous as its two components are continuous.

Comment: I did it as it makes sense for this precise example. However studying another function like $(x,y) \mapsto \frac{\cos y - 1}{y}$ it can be interesting to look at $\lim\limits_{y \to 0} \frac{\cos y - 1}{y}$ to study continuity for all the points $(x,0)$.